# CSS3 menu bar with rounded corners, I think I'm messing up the selectors

Tags: html, css, rounding

I have a ul for a navigation bar. In my CSS, I have a hover color transition. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="sideBarButton">
    <a href="www.google.com">
     Home
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="sideBarButton">
    <a href="www.google.com">
     About
    </a>
  </li>
       <li class="sideBarButton">
    <a href="www.google.com">
        Download
    </a>
  </li>
</ul> <!--- Navbar-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.sideBarButton {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px none #FFF;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
    opacity: 1;
}

.sideBarButton a {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(woodbutton.gif);
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 90px;
    display: block;
    color: black;
}
.sideBarButton a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
```

(Sorry for the slightly messy code, I've been meaning to sort through it and weed out the unneeded bits.) The buttons are pictures. I had the idea to round the two first-child and last-child selectors, but I think I've messed up somehow in (layering?) the selectors, for when I assign a class to the full ul, and set up a css selector (ex: .ulClass .sideBarButton:first-child) it doesn't do anything. What am I missing, and how would I fix it?

Thanks in advance! (NOTE: Ignore the class names, this is a top navbar, not a side, no matter what they might suggest!)

Edit: just to clarify, I want to round all four corners of the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the `li` instead of the class

```
.ulClass > li:first-child
 {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
   border-top-left-radius: 4px;   
 }
.ulClass > li:last-child
 {
   border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
   border-top-right-radius: 4px;   
 }
```

I also removed the offending style `Display:block` from `.sideBarButton a` which was causing the rounded corners not being applied.

Probably a good idea to clean up your code and take out the unnecessary styles.

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aSn8C/5/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for letting me know about display-block, but whenever I remove it the images disappear. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Edit: never mind, that was a different mistake I made editing. It still doesn't make rounded edges, but I think that is because .sideBarButton takes precedence over .ulClass>li, correct?

Comment: I devised a way to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/WyLGc/ But that seems like a lot of code, is there any way you can think to simplify it? I'm stuck.